# How to attach large info to a JPEG file?

Tags: jpeg, libjpeg

The APP0 to APP15 markers only support 65535 bytes each (I read this from libjpeg.doc). What if there's a bigger chunk of data to save in the jpeg file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no restriction on using multiple segments of the same type, depending on the data.

e.g, from Exif 2.2 specification, section 3.2

> Compressed files can record extended data exceeding 64 Kbytes by dividing it into multiple APP2 segments.

Answer (score 1):

Thats a lot of data.

Well if theres no other legit way then theres always steganography http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steganography